# ProxySQL data masking for multiple columns

Tags: regex, proxysql

I want to mask sensitive information on multiple columns in a table named `my_table` using ProxySQL.

I've followed this [tutorial](https://www.slideshare.net/profyclub_ru/inexpensive-datamasking-for-mysql-with-proxysql-data-anonymization-for-developers-rene-cannao-proxysql) to successfully mask a single column named `column_name` in a table using the following `mysql_query_rules`:

```
/* only show the first character in column_name */
INSERT INTO mysql_query_rules (rule_id,active,username,schemaname,match_pattern,re_modifiers,replace_pattern,apply)
          VALUES (1,1,'developer','my_table','(\(?)(`?\w+`?\.)?\`?column_name\`?(\)?)([ ,\n])','caseless,global', 
                "\1CONCAT(LEFT(\2column_name,1),REPEAT('X',CHAR_LENGTH(column_name)-1))\3 column_name\4",1);
```

But when I add a second rule for masking another column called `second_column_name` in the table, proxysql fails to mask the second column. Here's the second rule:

```
/* masking the last 3 characters in second_column_name */
INSERT INTO mysql_query_rules (rule_id,active,username,schemaname,match_pattern,re_modifiers,replace_pattern,apply)
          VALUES (2,1,'developer','my_table','(\(?)(`?\w+`?\.)?\`?second_column_name\`?(\)?)([ ,\n])','caseless,global', 
                "\1CONCAT(LEFT(\2second_column_name,CHAR_LENGTH(second_column_name)-3),REPEAT('X',3))\3 second_column_name\4",1);
```

Here's the query result after the 2 rules are added:

`SELECT column_name FROM my_table;` returns a masked `column_name`.

`SELECT second_column_name FROM my_table;` returns a masked `second_column_name`.

`SELECT column_name, second_column_name FROM my_table;` returns data with `column_name` masked, but `second_column_name` is not masked.

`SELECT second_column_name, column_name FROM my_table;` also returns data with `column_name` masked, but `second_column_name` is not masked.

Does this mean that 1 query can only be matched with 1 rule?

How can I mask data in multiple columns with ProxySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`flagIN`, `flagOUT`, and `apply`](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/wiki/Main-(runtime)#mysql_query_rules) allows me to mask data on multiple columns.

Here's the final `mysql_query_rules` I have:

```
/* only show the first character in column_name */
INSERT INTO mysql_query_rules (rule_id,active,username,schemaname,flagIN,match_pattern,re_modifiers,flagOUT,replace_pattern,apply)
          VALUES (1,1,'developer','my_db',0,'(\(?)(`?\w+`?\.)?\`?column_name\`?(\)?)([ ,\n])','caseless,global',6,    "\1CONCAT(LEFT(\2column_name,1),REPEAT('X',CHAR_LENGTH(column_name)-1))\3 column_name\4",0);
```

```
/* masking the last 3 characters in second_column_name */
INSERT INTO mysql_query_rules (rule_id,active,username,schemaname,flagIN,match_pattern,re_modifiers,flagOUT,replace_pattern,apply)
          VALUES (2,1,'developer','my_db',6,'(\(?)(`?\w+`?\.)?\`?second_column_name\`?(\)?)([ ,\n])','caseless,global',NULL,
                "\1CONCAT(LEFT(\2second_column_name,CHAR_LENGTH(second_column_name)-3),REPEAT('X',3))\3 second_column_name\4",1);
```

The meanings of the 3 variables are as the following:

- `flagIN`, `flagOUT`, `apply` - these allow us to create "chains of rules"
  that get applied one after the other. An input flag value is set to
  0, and only rules with flagIN=0 are considered at the beginning. When
  a matching rule is found for a specific query, flagOUT is evaluated
  and if NOT NULL the query will be flagged with the specified flag in
  flagOUT. If flagOUT differs from flagIN , the query will exit the
  current chain and enters a new chain of rules having flagIN as the
  new input flag. If flagOUT matches flagIN, the query will be
  re-evaluate again against the first rule with said flagIN. This
  happens until there are no more matching rules, or apply is set to 1
  (which means this is the last rule to be applied)